# Expanding clang -Wdocumentation flag to catch missing doxygen tags (@param, @tparam, @return)

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, doxygen, llvm-clang

I am currently looking into how to enforce our company coding standards using various tools provided by `llvm-clang`. One of the standards is that each c++ function must have accurate `doxygen` style documentation.

*Note*: I am currently using clang v6.0.0, *not* v9.

First I looked into the clang -Wdocumentation flag, but from my research it is missing a few of my required features:

1. Although all `@param`s and `@tparam`s in the doxygen are checked for corresponding parameters and template parameters in the associated function, missing `@param`s or `@tparam`s are not caught. I'd like to emit a warning in this case.
2. I'd also like to emit a warning if the order of the `@param`s in the doxygen doesn't match the order of the parameters in the function (same for `@tparam`s as well.

Next I looked into the `clang-tidy`, `clang-format` and other existing clang tools, but could not find anything customizable to meet my use cases.

Lastly I looked into creating my own standalone clang tool, but quickly became overwhelmed by the vast documentation (I am new to the whole clang experience). I tried following quite a few different promising leads, but with no concrete results.

Below is a simple c++ function semi-commented with doxygen:

```cpp
/// foo function
/// @param y second parameter
/// @param x first parameter
template <typename T>
int foo(int x, int y, int z) {
    ...
}
```

If I run `clang -Wdocumentation foo.cpp` on the code above, no errors are generated. I'd like the following errors to be generated:

1. parameters `y` and `x` are in the wrong order
2. parameter `z` is missing a `@param`
3. template parameter `T` is missing a `@tparam`
4. missing `@return`

Does anyone know if any existing tools can be customized to meet my requirements? If not, does anyone have any advice for how to approach making my own tool?

Comment: With the example given doxygen itself will give a warning (about `z`), you can catch the warnings in the `WARN_LOGFILE` file and process this file.

Comment: Thanks @albert that fixed errors 2 and 4! Looking at the doxygen configuration settings, I still couldn't figure out a way to check for missing `@tparam`s or out of order parameters. Do you know if there is a way to flag these are warnings/errors?

Comment: Regarding point 1) it is irrelevant for doxygen in which order the parameters are documented, this is left to the users (he might have a special reason for documenting the parameters in another order than in the call). Regarding point 4) I didn't quickly see a solution, feel free to submit an issue in the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new).

Comment: Regarding point 3) I've create an issue: "Warnings in case of tparam command" (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7089)